# Get user access tokens and authenticate request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, loopbackjs, strongloop

I believe to have spent many hours on decoding this box of pendora by [strongloop](https://strongloop.com/) REST framework for NodeJS. I have successfully managed to setup a [two factor authentication](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/two-factor-authentication-with-loopback/) module following the tutorial. That is working fine, with `mongo` setup as datasource for users.

I have 2 questions to ask:

1) Once the `User.Create()` is executed, the following model structure is stored in database and sent as a response to client.

```
{
  "id": "RMQ1dC03Ws8swaxPNvqKLPXEbOw6PcKYPisjsQgOuPmqmqJ0hEJKNzsjROppQAHy",
  "ttl": 86400,
  "created": "2015-08-17T18:18:56.158Z",
  "userId": "55d2259032786ce55eeed0fca",
  "user": {
    "email": "somemail@gmail.com",
    "id": "55d2259032786ce55eeed0fca"
  }
}
```

The `id` field is `accessToken` and `userId` is identifier against the user. `ttl` specifies the expiration time for the token, by default its 2 weeks, but if I `User.login()` anytime, a different accessToken is generated.

How should I validate any user request against any accessToken provided in the URL?

2) I want to create a `superUser` or `admin` user to access all the accessTokens against any user, the permission is denied by default. To do this I have created a user with `role admin` in the boot script:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var role = app.models.Role;
    var roleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;
    app.models.User.login({email: 'somemail@gmail.com', password: '124154'}, function(err, accessToken) {
                    if (err) return console.error(err);
                    console.log(accessToken);
                    role.create({
                        name:'admin'
                    }, function(err, rtnRole){
                        if (err) {
                          console.log('role error');
                          return console.error(err);
                      }
                      rtnRole.principals.create({
                          principalType: roleMapping.USER,
                          principalId: accessToken.userId
                      }, function(err, principal){
                          if (err) return console.error(err);
                          console.dir(principal);
                      });
                    });
                });

};
```

Output:

```
{ principalType: 'USER',
  principalId: '55d168c82de07a275c07921f',
  roleId: 1,
  id: 1 }
```

...Still this user is not authorized for accesstokens.. How should I get admin control? And authenticate any user request with tokens?

**UPDATE**

Having followed the steps provided by @Thibault, I am able to generate `acl` for admin. This is what my `model.json` looks like now:

```
{
  "name": "BudUser",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "index": {
        "unique": true
      }
    },
    "number": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "requestCode"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "loginWithCode"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

How to query `https://nodews-somedomain.c9.io:443/api/BudUsers/id/accessTokens` to get all `accessToken` of the user? And how to authenticate a user request that looks like:

`https://nodews-faizanjehangir.c9.io:443/api/BudUsers/getList?accessToken=214392174214jh21hgj12g4`

Also, should I be worried about tokens generation and expiration? Should I store them in database?

[image: User not authorized]

Comment: Can you show the ACL for the admin role in /common/models/model.json?

Answer (score 1):

You have to play with ACL, don't forget to use the generator:

`slc loopback:acl`

- Select the model to apply the ACL entry to: All existing models
- Select the ACL scope: All methods and properties
- Select the access type: All (match all types)
- Select the role: (custom) > admin
- Select the permission to apply: Explicitly grant access

If I remember AccessToken is a built-in Model, you have to "override" default acl for your specific role and make sure this role have the priority.

Don't forget to use debug:loopback* you will see what's happen (especially role's score).

Comment: I have followed the steps, generated acl.. please refer to the update provided in the question..